# Start point have different stroke width than other points

Tags: css, svg, polyline

Why stroke width differs for start point and other points?

Please refer the code below:

```html
   <svg>
      <polyline points="10 0, 30 0,10 10,30 10" fill="none" stroke-width="2px" stroke="#19af5c"></polyline>
    </svg>
```

I don't want to achieve by duplicating poly-line for other points. i.e each points have different `polyline`/`line` element

Comment: You mean the width of the top and bottom line?

Comment: Yes @hunzaboy..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because of how the stroke is done in SVG. It is done something like half-and-half, that is, the stroke is half from 0 to 1 and the other half is -1 to 0 (if you get what I mean) and so you see a thinner stroke.

You can refer the [Stroke section in this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes) to see what I mean. They've put it as follows:

> Strokes are drawn centered around the path

If you make the points as 10,1 and 30,1 you would see the same stroke width. Reason for this is that the stroke is now kind of between 0 to 2 on the Y-axis (half of the stroke is on top of the point and half is on the bottom).

```html
<svg>
  <polyline points="10 1, 30 1,10 10,30 10" fill="none" stroke-width="2px" stroke="#19af5c"></polyline>
</svg>
```